# How send Id to my view in redictionRoute Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

(Sorry for my english)

I'm making a subscribe system
(the flush is ok in database) than:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('organize_home',);
```

My Route of redirection needs an Id

```
/**
 * @Route("/mon-compte/{id}", name="organize_home")
 */
public function accountHomepage(User $user)
{
    return $this->render('user/organize_home.html.twig');
}
```

How can I send this id to the redirection ?

I tried to play with the user object but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('organize_home', ['id' => "MY_ID"] );
```

Or (PHP < 5.4)

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('organize_home', array('id' => "MY_ID") );
```

Symfony should then load the `User` with that ID and inject it into `accountHomepage(User $user)` automatically.

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer so that it closes the question.